# mysql query for returning overall ranks

Tags: mysql

I have a users table with the following data:

```
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | name       | points_game1 | points_game2 | points_game3 |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | player 1   |           10 |            0 |            5 |
|  2 | player 2   |            0 |           25 |            0 |
|  3 | player 3   |           30 |            3 |            0 |
|  4 | player 4   |            0 |            0 |           20 |
+----+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I want to be able to show overall ranks, where the ranking is defined as the overall highest score rather than a ranking per game.  So in the example above, what query would I use to display this result:

```
+----+------------+-------+----------------+
| id | name       | score | game           |
+----+------------+-------+----------------+
|  3 | player 3   |    30 | points_game1   |
|  2 | player 2   |    25 | points_game2   |
|  4 | player 4   |    20 | points_game3   |
|  1 | player 1   |    10 | points_game1   |
+----+------------+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: Have you looked into using `UNPIVOT` at all?

Comment: could you elaborate? iv'e never used this in mysql

Comment: `UNPIVOT` let's you take column names and make them part of the row: so for instance you'd end up with three rows per player, each row with four columns: id, name, game, points.  Except I just realized you're using MySQL, and `UNPIVOT` is not supported in MySQL.  Sorry.  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,379790 has an okay work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query answers your question:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  name, 
  GREATEST(points_game1, points_game2, points_game3) AS score,
  CASE
    WHEN points_game1 = GREATEST(points_game1, points_game2, points_game3) THEN 'points_game1'
    WHEN points_game2 = GREATEST(points_game1, points_game2, points_game3) THEN 'points_game2'
    WHEN points_game3 = GREATEST(points_game1, points_game2, points_game3) THEN 'points_game3'
  END AS game
FROM
  users
ORDER BY 
  3 DESC
```

A bit crude due to repetitiveness of the GREATEST(...) calculation. You may wish to put that in a subquery.

At any case, make note that this query will not utilize any index on the table since the ORDER BY uses a function over columns -- that negates usage of a key in MySQL.

Comment: Thanks! Works as asked. How would you change it to put the GREATEST in a subquery?

Comment: (hmmm, unable to properly format in this comment)

Like this:
'
 SELECT 
   id, 
   name, 
   score,
   CASE
  WHEN points_game1 = score THEN 'points_game1'
  WHEN points_game2 = score THEN 'points_game2'
  WHEN points_game3 = score THEN 'points_game3'
   END AS game
 FROM (
  SELECT *, GREATEST(points_game1, points_game2, points_game3) AS score FROM users
   ) sel_score
 ORDER BY 
   score DESC
`

Comment: What's the "sel_score" for? Also, which one is more efficient?

Comment: When using an inner query like I did, you must give it an alias. That's "sel_score".

Neither solutions are efficient. The latter also producing a temp table, so even less efficient.